# IReport with a big title

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report with a big title, so this report will have 2 pages with start text, and a small detail page.

How can I create a report with a big title, or 2 different reports to append on to another?

Any Ideia?

My version of iReport is 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  I solved it by creating a sub report and using it's Detail section as the report's title page.  I then put the sub report into a group header on the main report which would print first on the report.  It was a little hokey, but it worked.